# Javadoc cannot find classes written in scala

Tags: java, scala, javadoc

I am working on a project with mixed java and scala code. I am using maven for dependency management and IntelliJ IDEA for development. 
I have added the **maven-javadoc plugin** for generating the java documentation. However, it cannot find all the scala classes. It keeps on throwing errors as follows:

```
WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] /Users/mshinde/myproject-code/MLHighway/src/main/java/com/myproject/analytics/model/Project.java:12: cannot find symbol
[WARNING] symbol  : class SparkJoiner
[WARNING] location: package com.myproject.analytics.jobdriver
[WARNING] import com.myproject.analytics.jobdriver.SparkJoiner;
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] /Users/mshinde/myproject-code/MLHighway/src/main/java/com/myproject/analytics/model/DataSet.java:12: cannot find symbol
[WARNING] symbol  : class Transformer
[WARNING] location: package com.myproject.analytics.jobdriver
[WARNING] import com.myproject.analytics.jobdriver.Transformer;
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] /Users/mshinde/myproject-code/MLHighway/src/main/java/com/myproject/analytics/dataview/ImpalaView.java:3: cannot find symbol
[WARNING] symbol  : class SparkClassificationMetrics
[WARNING] location: package com.myproject.analytics.framework.evaluator
[WARNING] import com.myproject.analytics.framework.evaluator.SparkClassificationMetrics;
[WARNING] ^
[WARNING] /Users/mshinde/myproject-code/MLHighway/src/main/java/com/myproject/analytics/dataview/ImpalaView.java:212: package SparkClassificationMetrics does not exist
[WARNING] SparkClassificationMetrics.SparkMetrics sparkMetrics) {
[WARNING] ^
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      com/myproject/analytics
    scala/
      com/myproject/analytics
```

I am able to compile the project and run it. I just want to know how to get rid of the warnings? How do I get the javadoc to be able to find the scala classes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think JavaDoc is supposed to be able to generate docs for Scala - that's what ScalaDoc is for.  That said (with no personal experience to back this up) I would point you towards https://github.com/typesafehub/genjavadoc

Comment: I found two stach overflow questions  after search more. The links are http://stackoverflow.com/q/2046582/3874693  and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8359517/3874693